# Using Ethernet and Wifi at the same time in Android

Tags: android, networking, wifi, ethernet

i want to use turn on both Ethernet and Wifi on my android decive at the same time with different IP addresses like:

Wifi:
IP: 192.168.1.5
Gateway: 192.168.1.1

and

Ethernet:
IP:192.168.0.10
Gateway: (Blank)

Is it possible?
the problem is that when i turn Wifi on , the Ethernet will get disconnected.

and only when Wifi goes off or disconnected Ethernet will be connected!

How can i use both of them at the same time connected to the network?

It's possible in PC based systems even with 2-3 adapters!
But what about Android devices?

Comment: How are you trying to connect to Ethernet ? (programmatically) ?

Comment: I'm not sure, I guess on a rooted android... with busybox .. it can be done like for any other linux (with ifconfig)

Comment: ifconfig? how can i change it? i change the way and found that it's not easily possible...

Comment: Actually this question covers the point

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143534/android-ethernet-and-wi-fi-at-the-same-time