# i can't use wifi and ethernet at the same time on android

Tags: android

I have an api available in my local network that I must consume through ethernet and also I must connect to Wi-Fi to consume another service.

What happens is that every time I connect to the wifi the local api stops working.

I am occupying android 11.

I followed this post but I can't find where to edit this condition.

[Android Ethernet and Wi-Fi at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143534/android-ethernet-and-wi-fi-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Did you get the answer to this question? Can you share the solution if you have resolved it. Thanks