# What replaced ConnectivityServices in Android?

Tags: android, android-source

What replaced the ConnectivityServices in Android?

I have a USB OTG ethernet adapter I'm trying to use with a handset. I would like to be able to use Wifi and ethernet at the same time, but upon connecting the OTG ethernet adapter, the Wifi is disconnected. I found the following question(1) that suggests that ConnectivityServices.java is the culprit. However, this is a very old answer.

In the Android source(2) for that version of Android, 4.2.2_r1, the file is there. However, it appears this file was deleted around some time in 2017. I haven't been able to figure out what replaced the functionality.

I am currently working with an Android 12 device.

(1): [Android Ethernet and Wi-Fi at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143534/android-ethernet-and-wi-fi-at-the-same-time)

(2): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/services/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java

Comment: It's in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/modules/Connectivity/+/refs/heads/master/service/src/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java , extract from the framework to Mainline Module. But its logic is significantly changed. Good luck to you.

Comment: Thanks! If you want credit for that, please feel free to submit your response as an answer, and I will select it.